# Generate Scaffold CRUD for Identity using an "Admin Role" Net Core 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create an admin controller and custom views that allows me to use CRUD actions for the Identity generated tables in my net core 2.0 project when I choose to use Individual User Accounts auth. I already have defined my roles "**Admin**", "**Client**" and "**Employee**" to my users, so far my project has a default admin, and whenever an user registers into my project, the default role created for him is the **Client** one.

What I want to know is if there's a way to generate an scaffold with a controller and views to administrate users using CRUD actions whenever I'm logged as the admin, I want to know if that's possible, because when I try to generate a new scaffold using the model Models/AccountViewModels/RegisterViewModel.cs it says that:

`There was an error running the selected code generator
'The entity type 'RegisterViewModel' requires a primary key to be defined'`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate scaffolds using view models. Only entity types are supported. That said, just don't scaffold. It's training wheels for when you don't know how a controller should be structured. All you need is a class that inherits from `Controller` and has one or more public methods that return `IActionResult`.